# How do I specify the range for a particular argument of a function in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that gives the graph of an arbitrary polynomial over a quotient ring of the integers Z/nZ. In creating it, however, it became necessary that I create a function of multiple arguments, one whose range I need to specify. Here it is:

```
def prepoly(n,x):
    for k in range (bottom,0):
        return coef[k-bottom]*inv(x)^n  % ideal
    for k in range (0,1):
        return coef[-bottom]
    for k in range (1,top+1):
        return coef[k-bottom]*x^n % ideal
```

For this function, I want the range restrictions of k to be applied to the first argument only. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: You can add a if statement to check if `n` is between `bottom` and `zero` and other ranges and if not then you can raise an exception. Did that help? Maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: You are returning the first result of the first loop iteration, none of the rest of that function is even going to run, including the second iteration of the first loop. You might as well change the entire function to `return coef[0]*inv(x)^n  % ideal`. `0` because `bottom-bottom` (the first iteration) is `0`.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. How might I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what you are doing

```
for k in range (bottom,0):
    return coef[k-bottom]*inv(x)^n  % ideal
```

Unless bottom is 0, this is automatically going to return `coef[0]*inv(x)^n  % ideal`

---

```
for k in range (0,1):
    return coef[-bottom]
```

If bottom was 0, this will get hit and return `coef[-0]`

---

```
for k in range (1,top+1):
    return coef[k-bottom]*x^n % ideal
```

This will never get reached

---

The problem here is that `k` is arbitrary. I think what you are really trying to do is more like this. My conditions are probably wrong, because I don't understand what this is supposed to do, but this is much closer than what you currently have.

```
def prepoly(n,x):
    if bottom < 0:
        return coef[-bottom]*inv(x)^n  % ideal
    elif bottom == 0:
        return coef[0]
    else
        return coef[bottom]*x^n % ideal
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the first argument is between `bottom` and `top`. Try this:

```
def prepoly(n,x):
    if n > bottom and n < top:
        for k in range (bottom,0):
            return coef[k-bottom]*inv(x)^n  % ideal
        for k in range (0,1):
            return coef[-bottom]
        for k in range (1,top+1):
            return coef[k-bottom]*x^n % ideal
    else:
        return
```

This may not be what you're looking for, though. Could you be a bit clearer?

Comment: that isn't going to work. As soon as the first loop runs once the entire function will return and quit. Really, his function doesn't make any sense. At best, bottom will be 0, skipping the first loop and definitely returning the first iteration of the second loop.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, this should work better. @MichaelGuidry

Comment: see my answer to understand why the loops are never going to work, no matter how you wrap them.,